# Bootstrap carousel controls inline with indicators

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

By default, indicators are at the bottom and controls are left and right, respectively.

```
<div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Carousel indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>
    <!--/Carousel indicators-->
    <!-- Carousel items -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <h2>Item 1</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <h2>Item 2</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <h2>Item 3</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <h2>Item 4</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--/Carousel items-->
    <!-- Carousel nav -->
    <a class="carousel-control left" href="#carousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control right" href="#carousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    </a>
    <!--/Carousel nav-->
</div>
```

What's the best way to display controls inline with the indicators? What I want to achieve is placing left control to the left of the indicators and the right control to the right of the indicators. Inline, same height, vertically aligned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually something that's a little tricky to achieve because the carousel controls are positioned vertically with percentages and the carousel indicators are positioned vertically with pixels.  You can't just change one or the other without doing a little modifying.  Your best bet is going to be to use position percentages for both and just tweak it to your liking, but you'll also have to change the `.carousel-control {height:20px}` so that it matches the height of your indicators. Plus you'll also have to account for the change in font size of the chevrons from tablet to phone size.  Because of this you'll have to change the vertical height percentage through an @media query as well.  Here's a rough example of it in a fiddle with some very simple css changes.  Obviously you can tweak it by percentage to your liking. [Jake's Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3wxypoof/2/)

Comment: Thanks for your time. But I don't think this is the way to go. Unless I find a way to wrap indicators and controls together, the inline problem will stay.

Comment: I fixed the fiddle to make things more inline by putting the indicators and the controls in the same div and tweaking the css.  Check it out.  No more percentages :)

Comment: Not, I would have to wrap them together and remove 15% percentage from carousel-control and give them an exact width. Also font and line height has to be modified. Absolute positioning could be transformed into relative positioning and have all the navigation items at the bottom, BUT that means a lot of Bootstrap overriding...
THANKS!